# Forward HTTP requests to a private server

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api

We are currently running a web server on AWS and are thinking to add some RESTful APIs.  However, these  RESTful APIs will have to call 2 of other internal web services.  (by internal I meant, 1 sitting on AWS but only accessible by the web server, the other is a server on-premises with a VPN tunnel to this web server)

My question would be, is there a way to just host those RESTful APIs on those 2 internal web servers?  Maybe have the client call the public web server and somehow the public web server would forward or pass-through those calls to the 2 internal servers?  That way, we won't have to write and host additional web APIs on the public web server.

Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to do it with IIS rewrite?

Comment: Probably. these are pretty typical needs for a web server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your REST API must be public facing.

In my experience, it is best to have 1 exposed API and have all other resources to be handled on the backend of the API in which those external dependencies are on *private subnets*, so that way you can reduce the potential for security issues.

```
Public
    - RESTful API, RPC endpoints
    - Websites, etc
--------------------------------------
Private
    - Databases, queues 
    - VPN-tunnelled servers
    - additional servers / external resources
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use the Application Request Routing module + IIS URL Rewrite.

E.g. I have (A) http://publicsite.com and (B) http://privatesite.com where (B) hosts my RESTful APIs.

IIS ARR is configured with Reverse Proxy to rewrite http://publicsite.com/Api/* to route to http://privatesite.com/.

Client would then access, e.g., http://publicsite.com/Api/scores, IIS will then rewrite the request to http://privatesite.com/scores.

I have not yet tested this using HTTPS and I honestly do not know the security impact on this setup.  Anyone?